# LC3 - Compute Square Assembly

Tags: assembly, io, low-level, lc3, lc3-trap

Hi I'm writing a lc3 subroutine to compute the square of a value in n and then place that value in r0, i have wrote the code and it seems to be filling r0 with the sumofsums however at the end of the program the value in r0 ends up being x7fff - i'm not sure whats changing the value any ideas? my code is below

```
.orig x3FF8
 ld r1,n
ld r5,n
and r0,r0,#0
 square


add r0, r0,r1 ; add sum to r0

add r5,r5,#-1 ;decrement counter(amount of times to add sum)

brp square ;loop


theend



n .fill #4

.end
```

Comment: In comments on the OP's previous question, [they said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765417/lc3-assembly-square-of-n#comment82492877_47765521) there was a `LD R0, xFD7D` instruction changing `R0` after their code.

Comment: You seem to have left out the `halt` after the loop.  Won't execution continue into `.fill #4` and decode `n` as an instruction?  Is that the "load" instruction?

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried adding halt - no difference.

Comment: .fill is assigning 1 space in memory @PeterCordes

Comment: Yes, exactly.  What instruction does the byte `4` represent in LC-3 machine code?  Instructions are also just bytes in memory.  But if HALT didn't make a difference, then that's probably not the problem.

Comment: mhm so what can I do to approach this issue..? @PeterCordes seeing as taking the n.fill out is not an option as I need it for the program

Comment: Wait for someone else to answer this question, if you can't solve it yourself by learning more about how LC-3 works, or about the simulator you're using.

Comment: What LC3 simulator is being used?  I see no reason (aside from the lack of HALT statement) that this code would not work correctly.